# Loop ajax connect time out how fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have program extension chrome loop ajax more 150 time, but it connectimeout because too connect send to server.
How recive reponse success for next process

Fun ajax

```js
function compareImage(img1, img2, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "http://sv1.mysie.site/checkpoint?img1=" + encodeURIComponent(img1) + "&img2=" + encodeURIComponent(img2), true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback(xhr);
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

this is loop array

```js
for (var item in data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data[item].length; i++) {
    var link_image_one = data[item][i];
    for (var j = 0; j < image_fb.length; j++) {
      compareImage(link_image_one, image_fb[j], function(comp) {
        if (comp.response < 3) {
          console.log(item);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're flooding the server with 150 AJAX requests in a fraction of a second... You need to reduce that number of requests (by perhaps sending a single request with all data)

Comment: Hi, but program need send to request to server than 150 time. How fix.

Comment: Look into wrapping your AJAx calls in promises. Then you will have easier control over flow. that way you can group requests into batches etc. Look into the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) Much better than XMLHttpRequest, also it works with promises directly.

Comment: or use debounce to wait a few milliseconds before sending a new request.

Comment: @YunusSaha Debouncing is the wrong technique, if you debounced `compareImage` it would only execute once for the last image in the array.

Comment: @ ste2425 so how to process success 150 request without error 500

Comment: @YunusSaha using the techniques weve suggested, modify the server code so you can make the request in one go, batch the requests so you can make say 10 requests in one go, wait till they've finished then make 10 more. Or make the requests in series with possibly a small delay in the middle, either waiting for the previous to complete or not.